# In which scope my ajax data send from view to handler is stored in coldbox

Tags: ajax, coldfusion, coldbox

Please let me know answer if any one knows about it.In which scope my ajax data send from view to handler in coldbox

Comment: Please add code to your question. What do you have, what do you expect? Elaborate what exactly you do not understand. Help us to help you.

Comment: Actually i'm sending form data using jquery as following code $("#submit_btn").('submit', function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'deals/addmerchant', 
                type : "POST", 
                dataType : 'json',
                data : $("#MerchantForm").serialize(),
                },
                }
            })
        });

Comment: I'm dumping form data in handler as follows <cfdump var="#rc#"> ,BUT I'M NOT GETTING ANY DATA IN DUMP

Comment: If you're new to S.O., comments are frequently deleted. Could you please [edit] your question and add the code above, so it is more visible to others, and easier to read? :) Then delete the comments.

Answer (score 0):

When you're making an ajax POST, it gets treated as a brand new request.  This means you'll need a separate route and handler for that request.

Within your new handler (let's call it `/handlers/data.cfc`) you'll want to format your response appropriately for your code. ColdBox comes with some nifty tools to help you do this. One way would be to use [renderData()](https://coldbox.ortusbooks.com/digging-deeper/coldbox-proxy/the-event-handlers/renderdata) within your handler or view.

Rough example:

```
event.renderData( type="json", data=yourData );
```

Once set up correctly, the ajax calling code should receive the formatted data from your new handler as expected.

Side note: I recommend including code samples when asking questions on StackOverflow. It will help those that want to provide assistance understand exactly what you are trying to do.